# UIImagePickerController does not work correct on ios 9.3 iPad 4

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, uiimagepickercontroller

After update ipad to ios 9.3 images are stop to display. What can be wrong with it? On iOS 9 and iOS 9.2 that was work as well. On other devices iPhone devices all work fine.

```
 private func presentPickerForLibrary() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: don't show preview]

[image: don't show preview]

Comment: One obvious problem here is that your app is not an iPad app.

Comment: Yes but anyway this also should work on iPad

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the problem, so I have to guess based on what I've got. :)

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well on iPad mini 2, iOS 9.3. My app is also iPhone-only app and previously it is working ok on iPad. One thing to note is, the thumbnails are seem to be loaded ok, but then overlayed with the grey rectangle. To see them, tap the Camera Roll (works better with huge camera roll), and do a fast scroll, you'll see the thumbnails but as soon as you stop scrolling, the grey overlay shows up instead :(

Comment: This might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183117/ios-9-3-uiimagepickercontroller-memory-issue

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on iPhone 6s. It seem to be related to iCloud photos. In my case only a few of the images were blank. One of our testers experienced it with iCloud off (iPad mini 2). Many users are experiencing this since the 9.3 update. No clue yet :(

Comment: I can confirm that 9.3.1 hasn't fixed this issue. I've noticed that the Vivino app has the same issue but Skype does not. They both use the `UIImagePickerController`. A restart fixed it in my case but not for our tester...

Comment: I can now confirm it only happens on iPhone Only apps on iPad not all iPad Apps

Comment: Hi. I've having this issue. Did any of you managed to solve it at all? UIImagePickerController does exactly as what's being described here, in that the App, (my App) being an iPhone App has broken on all iPads from 4, Air, Pro etc... The Camera Roll displays tiles for all photos present but does not display the thumb at all.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be linked to iCloud Photo Library setting. Turning this on in Preferences fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this as well in an older, non-universal, iPhone app when running it on an iPad running iOS 9.3. I do not see it when running on an iPad simulator, only an actual device.

I am not seeing it in a newer, universal iPhone/iPad app. It looks like the issue is only affecting iPhone apps when run in 2x/1x mode on an iPad running iOS 9.3.x

It looks like there is an open Rdar ticket describing the issue, https://openradar.appspot.com/25813088.

I also came across a thread on the Apple developer forms also describing the issue, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43400.

The iPhone app I'm testing with is still using the now deprecated `ALAssets` API. It looks like `[ALAsset thumbnail]` is returning `nil` when running an iPhone app on an iPad running iOS 9.3.x, this may be related to why the `UIImagePickerController` is not displaying thumbnails.

Comment: I agree that if you turn on iCloud photo library then the photos from there will show up.  I have optimize photo for iCloud photo library turned on.  Maybe this is something.  I noticed that if I have the app set to iPad it works and there are six thumbnails shown instead of four when on the iPhone app.  I see that there has been a bug report about this.  I hope they resolve it soon.  It would be a big pain to have to adapt my app to universal.

Comment: If anyone have a solution, let me know :)