# UIImagePickerController's thumbnail issue on iPad with iOS (!)9.3.2 on iPhone targeted apps?

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

My application is configured to use iPhone Devices only. In my app I am using `UIImagePickerController`. On iPhone devices and iPad devices with iOS 9.3.1 the thumbnails of Photo Library is presenting without any issues, but on iPad devices under iOS 9.3.2.
Any ideas how to fix it without changing the TARGET from 'iPhone' to 'Universal'?  :)
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBAction func touched(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    //
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    //
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController does not work correct on ios 9.3 iPad 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289929/uiimagepickercontroller-does-not-work-correct-on-ios-9-3-ipad-4)

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems from apple. After reviewing your code it seems like all ok. Instead of accessing the album view, you can try to access the phot0 view of image picker.
 Try UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum as source type.